# How can I properly make divs sit side by side without wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I understand the idea that you can use inline-blocks to get divs to sit next to each other and you can use nowrap on the parent to make sure they don't wrap.  My problem is that putting any div inside those makes the following divs push down.  I've created a jsfiddle to show the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/MMtNQ/2/

The gist of the html is this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="side-by-side">
        <div>Text here</div>
        <div>Text here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-by-side">
        <div>Text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the divs are adjusted downward because of the div I have in the first one.  How can I get them all to align to the top?

Answer (score 5):

add  `vertical-align: top;` to the `.side-by-side`  definition

```
.side-by-side {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/EHD3X/).

Comment: That's where I was headed, too, though I can't explain why the first div is high and the others low. I'd like to hear an explanation.

Comment: Ya, I don't understand why this fixes it, I thought vertical-align applied to the content inside, not the element itself.

Comment: @weexpectedTHIS Inline block by default aligns baseline, and browsers don't always do a good job of figuring this out, especially with elements of varying content.  See [this page](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) for a pretty good explanation.